# What does a nucleus look like?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics

It's a Christmas time and so I hope I'll be pardoned for asking a question which probably doesn't make much sense :-)

In standard undergraduate nuclear physics course one learns about models such as [Liquid Drop model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-drop_model) and [Shell model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model) that explain some properties of nucleus.

But as I understand it these models are purely empirical and most importantly *incompatible*. Perhaps it's just my weak classical mind but I can't imagine same object being described as a liquid with nucleons being the constituent particles floating freely all around the nucleus and on the other hand a shell model where nucleons occupy discrete energy levels and are separated from each other.

Now I wonder whether these empirical models are really all we've got or whether there are some more precise models. I guess one can't really compute the shape of the nucleus from the first principles as one can do with hydrogen atom in QM. Especially since first principles here probably means starting with QCD (or at least nucleons exchanging pions, but that is still QFT). But I hope there has been at least some progress since the old empirical models. So we come to my questions:

> 1. Do we have a better model for description of a nucleus than the ones mentioned?
> 2. How would some nuclei (both small and large) qualitatively look in such a better model? *Look* here means that whether enough is known so that I could imagine nucleus in the same way as I can imagine an atom (i.e. hard nucleus and electrons orbiting around it on various orbitals).
> 3. What is the current state of first-principles QCD computations of the nucleus?

Comment: Relevant link - [Nucleons in platinum nucleus seem to move in a coordinated fashion](http://www.nature.com/news/2010/100824/full/4661034a.html?s=news_rss) One more link - [One-neutron halo nucleus Be-11](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2607)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give you a real answer but I figured this may be better than nothing:

1. I don't know of any better model, although I'm not an expert in nuclear physics so I can't be sure one doesn't exist.
2. I suspect that any better model would not give a nice neat physical picture of the nucleus, the way we have a nice neat physical picture of the atom. In particular, I wouldn't expect to see a model that predicts concentric wavefunctions for nucleons, the way quantum mechanics describes electrons. Protons and neutrons are complex composite particles with many internal (and external) interactions, so their wavefunctions will tend to be much more localized than those of electrons. This is one case where the classical particle model actually is not too bad.
3. From what I've heard (from people who know this business), the current state of the art in lattice QCD computations is calculating the mass of the proton with some accuracy. They're a long way away from being able to actually simulate a whole nucleus.

Comment: Thanks David. So if I understood you correctly, you are saying that I shouldn't expect any positive answer to my question. Still, I'd like to think that we can solve (numerically at the very least) small neuclei by assuming certain structure of neutrons and protons (I think their mass/charge distributions are pretty well known?) and certain effective residual strong force between them?

Answer (score 3):

When you get down to these length scales, you have to be careful with words such as "look". In my mind, the "answer" for this question requires a roundabout in the philosophical area.

"Look" - what does it mean in physics? Even more relevant: "is". When a physicists uses the word "is", s/he is really using a shortcut for saying "behaves as it would be", that is, it behaves according to some model (this is a realization that took a couple of years for me to reach. Of course, I might change it in the future as I continue my physics intake). This is not only true for quantum physics, but in the macroscopic world, the distinction is often thought of as not as important. No one can deny the following though: a rod is a model for a certain object, and we can prescribe this model to real-life objects and calculate. In some cases, the physical object that we one day called a rod might be called a spring, depending on what we want to do. What "is" the object? In the physicists eyes, it is both a rod and a spring, and there is no incompatibility, as long as one knows what one is doing. What does it "look" like? It depends on the length scale and the application.

In the quantum world, de Broglie says that the constituents are both particles and waves. Contradiction? No.

How does a nucleus "look"? Which model is "right"? It depends. How I would intuitively imagine it in my mind is as a continuous domain of a charge (strong/weak/EM) cloud. Is this "correct"? It is one possible model, that works well in some applications. In other applications, it is just a hard sphere/wave/point/oscillator...

Sorry about the flaky amateur-philosophical mumbo-jumbo :-) Question to think about: what does "is" mean for a physicist (or a mathematician, or many other people).

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to down-vote this. I am very well aware of all the conceptual problems there might be but I still believe (some of) my questions should make sense in the same way it makes sense to say "atom is so and so big". This doesn't mean to say that outer electron shell is precisely localized. But we know theory tells us that electron probability density is sharply concentrated around its maximum and so we are allowed to create a mental model of atom as electrons orbiting it on precise paths. As long as we understand that it is just a simplification, all is fine.

Comment: The size of the atom is not defined - it depends on the model. Do we look at electrical charge? Mass? The radius is different. I think you still have some thinking to do concerning models and reality, not to be crude.

Comment: (Hitting "Enter" in comments is apparently a no-no :-) ). The shell model of the atom is not a good picture overall. It explains some things from a macroscopic perspective, but it fails hard at atomic distances. If you accept the shell model for the atom as the "true" intuitive model, you might just as well accept the point model of the nucleus, is what I mean. They both work well. If we probe deeper and deeper, do we find strings? Who knows.

Comment: I think you are being harsh Marek. Electrons dont orbit on precise paths, as you say they are probablities. That mental model is a fudge - the 'look' is actually incorrect as the electron could be anywhere. I think Daniel didn't do a bad job at defining the problem between defining something micro with macro terms like 'appearance'. The appearance is inherently random. It is probably fair to say that the two theories in your OP are right, depending on how you interact with the nucleus. The nucleus 'looks' like both of them. I find the shell model more satisfying to visualise myself

Comment: Not a bad explanation, really. But it may be disappointing for most non-physicists

Comment: I used to think I'm a uber-hippy, but this answer proves me wrong. -1 @daniel. Even seen as a philosophical observation, your answer makes little sense as an answer to @marek's question.

Comment: "The shell model of the atom is not a good picture overall. It explains some things from a macroscopic perspective, but it fails hard at atomic distances."

Ok. I have no idea what you're talking about.

"If you accept the shell model for the atom as the "true" intuitive model, you might just as well accept the point model of the nucleus, is what I mean. They both work well. If we probe deeper and deeper, do we find strings? Who knows."

Comment: @Daniel: I don't like the way all your talk eventually fades into philosophical blabbering. Do you care to elaborate why shell model of atom is not a good picture? Because it holds down to QED: electron is to be found on average in the areas predicted by QM (and in particular usually around maximum) and is kept there by exchanging photons with the nucleus. It also has quite sharp value of the momentum (whose distribution is, of course, just FT of its position distribution) so it's safe to say it has certain velocity. The picture is correct all the way down with minor corrections.

Comment: @SoulmanZ: I disagree. As I said the model is good as long as one is aware that it is just a model and understands perfectly in what regards it fails. This can be done with shell model of an atom and I am asking for the same thing with nucleus. Any talk besides this (and in particular all of Daniel's answer) is just philosophy with no content and, worst of all, with no relation to my question.

Comment: @belisarius: no it doesn't. Everyone knows that size of atom corresponds to the position of its outer electron shell (most importantly, atoms and outer shells are fundamental building blocks of chemistry). If you are going to hit the atom with some high energy particles you are not probing atom anymore, you are probing nucleus. Could you instead provide a paper that would argue that the size of atom is anything else than what I mentioned?

Comment: @belisarius: physicists talk about these things all the time. I suggest you ask them next time you see one ;-) For now, I think this article clarifies my points pretty well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius -- in particular the sentence "Despite these conceptual difficulties, under most definitions the radii of isolated neutral atoms range between 30 and 300 pm (trillionths of a meter), or between 0.3 and 3 angstroms."

Comment: @space_cadet: I started my post by saying that I wanted to give a philosophical answer, so yes, it's "vague" if one expects equations. Calling it "hippie", with a derogatory undertone, is shallow. It is a very relevant train of thought for anyone in theoretical physics that inevitably must be dealt with when one starts juggling different descriptions and models around for entities which are by it's nature not directly visible. I disagree with your conclusion that it is irrelevant to the question (but if I hadn't disagreed, I shouldn't have written the answer to begin with, presumably :-) ).

Comment: @Marek: From your OP: "Perhaps it's just my weak classical mind but I can't imagine same object being described as [model 1] and on the other hand [model 2]" - This statement clearly indicates that you are not aware of the distinction between model and object. That's why I went on my philosophical rant. You seem to want to see things as very certain, but this doesn't happen at the quantum level. http://www.hydrogenlab.de/elektronium/HTML/einleitung_hauptseite_uk.html also expresses these thoughts but in a different way. Page 2 is almost eerily connected with your original question.

Comment: @daniel my intention was not to be derogatory and I apologize if I came across that way. However you yourself described your answer as "flaky amateur-philosophical mumbo-jumbo :-)". You were probably kidding, but it truly came across that way. If you wish you can always add to your answer to help us physicists appreciate your views better.

Comment: @Daniel: no it only indicates that you didn't understand that part at all. I mentioned it to indicate that those two models are incompatible and presumably neither of them captures very accurately what actually happens with the real object and therefore are not very useful for me (though each of them may be useful in a certain domain and for certain specific questions). Therefore I am looking for a better model; hence my question.

Comment: @Daniel: I can assure you that it *is* irrelevant to the question, simply because I find it irrelevant and I know what I am asking for (I am not sure you do know that, though). And I disagree with the statement that this is a relevant train of thought in theoretical physics. It was just a philosophical and metaphysical nonsense and none of that was required for my direct questions.

Comment: @space_cadet: When one approaches the theoretical domain, this _is_ physics. Earlier in history the discipline was called "natural philosophy", which many feel [citation needed] theorists are heading towards again (not only string theory). I were in the theoretical domain before I ended up in experimental subatomic physics, which makes me see the subatomic world in a wider picture than I personally did before my excursion. It's very useful to comfortably be able to differ between "reality" and measurable quantities for me in my work. I can't say more than my original final rhetorical question.

Comment: @Marek: I interpreted your original question as a confusion of "model" and "reality". If that's out of the way, I recommend the Be-11-paper in voix's links, which names a few more "precise" current theoretical models which can make nuclear predictions where the other models fail (far from stability, etc.). The paper's references (or Google in general) can lead to more hardcore explanations of the models, I'm sure. Don't expect as intuitively nice models as the shell model, though. The strong force is far from understood in a trivial way.

Comment: @Daniel: thanks for talking physics at last :-) I never expected anything trivial in the first place (and I think I also stated that somewhere in the question, implicitly at least).

Answer (score 2):

> In standard undergraduate nuclear physics course one learns about models such as Liquid Drop model and Shell model that explain some properties of nucleus.
>
> But as I understand it these models are purely empirical and most importantly incompatible.

This is not really true.

They're not incompatible. The liquid drop model can be obtained as the classical limit of the shell model.

They're not purely empirical. The shell model is usually done using a residual interaction that is empirically determined, but that doesn't mean the model is purely empirical.

We can't define what a nucleus "looks like" in the optical sense because it doesn't interact with photons in ways that would allow that. But the mean field basically has the form of a sphere or prolate ellipsoid in almost all cases. This shape can fluctuate about the equilibrium, just like with any quantum-mechanical oscillator.

> What is the current state of first-principles QCD computations of the nucleus?

Very small systems like the deuteron are somewhat doable. But in general QCD is neither necessary nor a sufficient for doing nuclear structure calculations. You're dealing with an n-body problem that is essentially intractable unless you can find tricks to make it tractable. For a nucleus with mass number $A$, we have $n=A$ if we treat it using nucleons as the particles, $n=3A$ if we use quarks (not even counting the gluons). There is no reason to make the problem even more intractable by tripling $n$. Low-energy nuclear structure is nonrelativistic, and there is simply no advantage to using a quark model.

Answer (score -2):

QM model of the nucleus is possible, but is incompatible to quark model and QCD, being incompatible with whole idea that nucleus consists of protons and neutrons (the proton-neutron model).

To have QM model of nucleus would require to start from the very beggining. It is hardly possible. It is a lot of work and no warranty of success :)